# c++ reference parameters function

Tags: c++, function, parameters, reference

I dont know why this program wont run. The values in getStockInfo are supposed to be stored in reference parameters. Then displayStatus accepts them as arguments. I know it has something to do with getStockInfo and displayStatus in main and when they are defined, i just cant figure it out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

void getStockInfo(int &, int&, double&);
void displayStatus(int, int, double, double);

int main()
{
//Declare Variables
int orderedSpools;
int spoolsStock;
double specialCharges;
int spoolsOrdered;

int backOrder;
double subtotal,
       shipping,
       total;


cout << "Middletown Wholesale Copper Wire Company" << endl;

getStockInfo(spoolsOrdered, spoolsStock, specialCharges);

displayStatus(spoolsOrdered, spoolsStock, specialCharges);

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void getStockInfo(int &spoolsOrdered, int &spoolsStock, double &specialCharges)
{
char ship; 

cout << "How many spools would you like to order: ";
cin >> spoolsOrdered;

//Validate the spools ordered 
while(spoolsOrdered < 1)
{
    cout << "Spools ordered must be at least one" << endl;
    cin >> spoolsOrdered;
}

cout << "How many spools are in stock: ";
cin >> spoolsStock;

//Validate spools in stock
while(spoolsStock < 0)
{
    cout << "Spools in stock must be at least 0" << endl;
    cin >> spoolsStock;
}

cout << "Are there any special shipping charges? ";
cout << "Enter Y for yes or another letter for no: ";
cin >> ship;

//Validate special charges
if(ship == 'Y' || ship == 'y')
{
    cout << "Enter the special shipping charge: $";
    cin >> specialCharges;
}
else
{
    specialCharges = 10.00;
}
}

void displayStatus(int spoolsOrdered, int spoolsStock, double specialCharges,
                   double total)
{
double backOrder,
       subtotal,
       shipping,
       total;
int itemsReady;


cout << "Items ordered: " << spoolsOrdered << endl;
cout << "Items ready to ship: " << spoolsStock << endl;


if(spoolsOrdered > spoolsStock)
{
    backOrder = spoolsOrdered - spoolsStock;
    cout << "Items on backorder: " << backOrder << endl;
}


subtotal = itemsReady * 100;
cout << "Subtotal: " << subtotal << endl;

shipping = specialCharges;
cout << "Shipping: " << shipping << endl;

total = subtotal + shipping;
cout << "Total Due: " << total << endl;



}
```

Comment: If by "won't run", you mean has a compiler error, show that error.

Comment: You just asked [another question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15755391). You have to do some research before you fire off another question and at least give credit to the people who helped you solve the initial problem... and looking at this further, it is not the same issue but closely related. You didn't even make the effort to change the calling code after changing the prototype and definition.

Comment: @Fred Thomsen Oh go whine somewhere else. Its not closely related at all. I fixed it all good now I was stuck on one part and needed help

Comment: @user1807815: The question you asked was very closely related, it wasn't Fred's fault that he didn't *guess* that you had an (another) unrelated compile error that you chose not to show.  This is not the place for you to tell people who are trying to help to 'stop whining', improve your questions, then you will get better answers.  He's right, though - you have yet to give credit to the people who helped you with the previous question, do so by selecting which answer you will go for, and then they will get their credit by having their reputation increased.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you declared `displayStatus`:

```
void displayStatus(int, int, double, double);
```

Here is how you use `displayStatus`:

```
displayStatus(spoolsOrdered, spoolsStock, specialCharges);
```

***Do you see a difference?***

*Hint:* count the number of parameters in each line.

Comment: Yeah i see it, i dont know what i was thinking. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
void displayStatus(int spoolsOrdered, int spoolsStock, double specialCharges,
                   double total)  //**<-- here: total as parameter**
{
double backOrder,
       subtotal,
       shipping,
       total;  //**<-- and here: total as local variable**
int itemsReady;
```

On your code above, I found that you have a redundancy. I marked it.
You have two variables under the same name, *total*, one is a parameter of displayStatus function, and another one is local variable of displayStatus function.

When I see your code line by line, this *total* variable did not perform any computation in main function neither in getStockInfo function. The only computation of *total* variable is happening in displayStatus function. Therefore, I suggest you, better *delete* variable *total* on the parameter of displayStatus function. It will not hurt your code, because you already have your local variable *total*.

**EDIT**: You do not need *total* variable in the main function, so, *delete* this variable.